# Why do factory functions with keys that have same name values only change the value when given a parameter

Tags: javascript

In:
function f(sex) {
return : {
sex: sex,
}
}
if I do:
const Leopard = f(blue)
Leopard will be an object that has {sex: blue,}, my question is why does sex (the key) not change, and is it not encombering to not be able to change the key.

Comment: Because keys are identifiers, not variable names. But if you did `return {[sex]:sex}` then it would indeed evaluate the key and you'd get `{blue:"blue"}` back - assuming it's actually a string.

Comment: I don't think I would ever have thought to ask this question, but it's a very perceptive qustion to ask IMHO.

Comment: For your next question, I suggest including a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). That way you'd catch the syntax errors in the example before posting (the colon after `return`, the missing quotes on `blue`, ...).

Answer (score 2):

In the object literal `{sex: sex}`, the property key (name) is **hardcoded** to be `sex`. The *value* comes from the parameter `sex`, but the *name* is hardcoded.

If you wanted to change both, you could use the value from the parameter as the property name by using *computed* property name syntax:

```
return {[sex]: sex};
//      ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− computed property name syntax uses
//                            the value from the `sex` parameter
```

Example:

```js
function f(sex) {
    return { [sex]: sex, };
}

const leopard = f("blue");
console.log(leopard);
```